# Foundation 5 custom sass project setup

Tags: zurb-foundation, compass-sass, compass, zurb-foundation-5

I have a project that I would like to use foundation 5 with. I have been through the steps of creating a new foundation project using the CLI but I don't like it. There is too many files and the structure does not match what I want. So...

I am intending to add only the required files to my project and use compass to compile all the css.

I have noticed in the project created on the CLI a few things that confuse me and would like some help in clearing them up.

- In the project created on the CLI there are two `_settings.scss` files one under the foundation directory in bower_components and one in `MY_PROJECT\scss`. I'm assuming that because of this `add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"` line in the `config.rb`, which of those files has preference?
- Why does `MY_PROJECT/stylesheets` not have normalize.css (or foundation.css) in it? And how are they not there? (in my custom setup they are being generated, albeit in subdirectories of `stylesheets`, also the `foundation.css` that is being generated for me has no settings changes applied so I guess it shouldn't be being generated)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look inside `\bower_components\foundation\scss` you'll see the file `foundation.scss`. That file imports all the stylesheets for all the additional components that come in the Foundation 5 "package." In your root `scss` directory, the `app.scss` is what compiles the SASS into `\stylesheets\app.css`. So rather than this:

```
@import "foundation";
```

Uncomment the individual components you'll be using. Something like this:

```
@import
   //"foundation/components/accordion",
   //"foundation/components/alert-boxes",
   "foundation/components/block-grid",
   //"foundation/components/breadcrumbs",
   //"foundation/components/button-groups",
   //"foundation/components/buttons",
   "foundation/components/clearing",
   "foundation/components/dropdown",
   //"foundation/components/dropdown-buttons",
   //"foundation/components/flex-video",
   "foundation/components/forms",
   "foundation/components/grid",
   //"foundation/components/inline-lists",
   //"foundation/components/joyride",
   //"foundation/components/keystrokes",
   //"foundation/components/labels",
   //"foundation/components/magellan",
   //"foundation/components/orbit",
   //"foundation/components/pagination",
   //"foundation/components/panels",
   //"foundation/components/pricing-tables",
   //"foundation/components/progress-bars",
   "foundation/components/reveal",
   "foundation/components/side-nav",
   //"foundation/components/split-buttons",
   "foundation/components/sub-nav",
   //"foundation/components/switches",
   "foundation/components/tables",
   //"foundation/components/tabs",
   //"foundation/components/thumbs",
   //"foundation/components/tooltips",
   "foundation/components/top-bar",
   "foundation/components/type",
   "foundation/components/offcanvas",
   "foundation/components/visibility";
```

If you'd like to streamline your file structure, I would suggest you remove any scss files from the `\bower_components\foundation\scss\foundation\components` directory that you will not use. Same with the `js` directory. You don't actually need to modify anything in the `bower_components` directory to get everything to work. Not entirely sure why it's all contained within `bower_components`, but I imagine it's got something to do with being able to update the core components later with future releases.

Someone else could probably give a more educated answer.

p.s. - make sure to `compass watch` in your CLI to see any of those changes made to your SASS files.